# Excel cell multiple validation between two dates and if cell is not blank

Tags: excel

I require a cell to be validated twice. Firstly, if the user has inputted a time (B5) but not a date (A5) then a pop-up should appear requesting a date in A5. When the date is entered it must be between the start date (B1) and end date (B2).

[image]

Comment: I can use the data validation tool to validate A5 between start date and end date. But I don't know how to request A5 to be filled if B5 is not blank as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something simple since your cells are all hardcoded.  You can edit the macro as you see fit to have more functionality and to be more robust.

```
Sub doubleValidate()
    If ActiveSheet.Cells("B5") <> "" And ActiveSheet.Cells("A5") = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Please Enter Date!")
        End
    End If

    If ActiveSheet.Cells("A5") <= ActiveSheet.Cells("B2") And ActiveSheet.Cells("A5") >= ActiveSheet.Cells("B1") Then
        MsgBox ("All good.")
    End If

    If ActiveSheet.Cells("A5") > ActiveSheet.Cells("B2") Or ActiveSheet.Cells("A5") < ActiveSheet.Cells("B1") Then
        MsgBox ("Date not in range.")
    End If

End Sub
```

Next time please show some of your own work in order to get a solid answer.